NTFS not accessible on Ubuntu Budgie 24.04
I have installed fresh Ubuntu Budgie 24.04. I am unable to access the Windows NTFS filesystem. Initially I was unable to access Windows data. Then I created a new NTFS partition. Initially it was working in Ubuntu, but now it's not working. How to fix it?


Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

The following commands have worked for me:
sudo ntfsfix --clear-dirty /dev/yourdiskAndPartition_here
sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/yourdiskAndPartition_here
For example :
sudo ntfsfix --clear-dirty /dev/sda4
sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/sda4

Thanks, you save me! it is working on my new ubuntu 24.04.1

Could be due to a bug in Ubuntu 24.04 with NTFS, without a fix yet. See:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g/+bug/2062972
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/2063985
https://github.com/tuxera/ntfs-3g/issues/108
Error Mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/ on Ubuntu 24.04

